# Секция с контентом привязанным к скроллу

Tags: jquery, css

Всем доброго времени суток.Такой вопрос:Как реализовать подобное: секция, в ней какой-то контент и он статичен, далее следует еще одна секция, но находящийся в ней контент(блоки текста) привязан к скроллу, с эффектом примерно как в плагине superscrollorama, то есть он будет перемещаться горизонтально в зависимости от скролла и вертикально с фиксированным бэкграундом.А после этой секции следует еще одна и контент в ней статичен.Если нужны какие-то пояснения, то дам их.

Comment: Картинка или схема не помешала бы.

Comment: я бы с удовольствием..вот только как отобразить это не знаю.в голове то есть.в общем, еще раз но покороче:первая секция со статичным контентом, вторая с эффектом примерно как вот на этом наикрутейше сделанном сайте http://makeyourmoneymatter.org, то есть она с динамичным контентом привязанным к скроллу, а третья секция снова со статичным контентом

Comment: примерно как это реализовать я понимаю но проблема будет заключаться в том что перед динамичной секцией будет находит еще одна или несколько и нужно чтобы скролл и перемещение срабатывали лишь при ее появлении..